# Java Error: first type: double, second type: String

Tags: java, variables, operators

I just started learning Java programming, and received this error on my first project in the last part, "fee before taxes" I must be messing up my variables, but I am not sure. Any ideas?

This is the error I receieved on the compiler:

> error: bad operand types for binary operator
>
> first type:  double
>
> second type: String
>
> 2 errors

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project1Naja {

  public static void main(String[] args) {  

     String firstName; // To hold first name
     String lastName; // To hold last name
     String hours; // Child's hours   
     final String date; // Date of Service
     final double RATE; // Hourly rate
     final double TAX_RATE; // Tax percentage
     int fee; // Cost before tax added
     int taxAmount; // Tax total
     double totalFee; // Fee including tax

     // Scanner created to read input.
     Scanner childCare = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.print("Enter your first name: " );
     firstName = childCare.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter your last name: " );
     lastName = childCare.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: " );
     hours = childCare.nextLine();

     System.out.print("Enter date here: " );
     date = childCare.next();    

     System.out.println("Child Care Service Bill For: " + firstName 
                    + lastName);
     System.out.println("Date of Service: " + date);    


     System.out.println("Number of hours: " + hours);    
     System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " = RATE * hours); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize local variables before accessing them,

in this case `RATE` is local variable which is uninitialized at the time it is being accessed

```
 System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " = RATE * hours);
```

initialize it by

```
 final double RATE = 0.50; // some rate value
```

and also `String` cannot be multiplied with `double`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I am on chapter 2 of 1200 page book. So, I am not 100% sure what you mean by I need to initialize the variable first. Would you mind elaborating a little bit more please?

Comment: That's another thing I am trying to figure out, is what data type I can use that would be good for both. The book I am reading is clear to a point.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to note here..

1. `String hours;`

hours is string so you cannot multiply any variable with a string

2. `System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " = RATE * hours);`

wrong syntax... it should be `System.out.println("Fee before taxes: =" + RATE * hours);`

also RATE and whatever you multiply with it plz initialize both.

Comment: initializing means you need to give them some default value like 
double RATE = 0  and int hours = 1 something like this

Comment: Good information guys, thank you. I totally missed the wrong syntax. I am trying to change my data type for hours to something that I thought would work like final double RATE = ..., or double RATE, but I am still receiving a compiler error. "incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int,...etc" I am not sure what other data type I am supposed to be using after trying the ones that seemed appropiate.

Comment: You can concert it to int as Integer.parseInt (hours)

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile because **Firstly** the `=` out of `" "` is for assignement, so the first thing to do is to keep it inside the `"Fee before taxes:  "`.

**Second**, you can't use the Multiplication Operator `*` between `String` and a `double`, in order to do that you need to parse the `String` like that: `Double.parseDouble(hours)`.

**Third**, you need to initialize **all local variables (`final` or not) before using them** as they don't have default values in Java, you can learn mor about local variables from the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

It's also detailed in the [Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html#jls-16.1):

> For every access of a local variable or blank final field x, x must be
>   definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.

So, for your example, the only variable used before assignement is `RATE`, so you don't have to initialize the others:

```
final double RATE = 0; // for example
```

At the end, your code must look something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

  public class project1Naja {

  public class project1Naja {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String firstName; // To hold first name
        String lastName; // To hold last name
        String hours; // Child's hours
        final String date; // Date of Service
        final double RATE = 0; // Hourly rate
        final double TAX_RATE = 0; // Tax percentage
        int fee; // Cost before tax added
        int taxAmount; // Tax total
        double totalFee; // Fee including tax

        // Scanner created to read input.
        Scanner childCare = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = childCare.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = childCare.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter the child's hours here: ");
        hours = childCare.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter date here: ");
        date = childCare.next();

        System.out.println("Child Care Service Bill For: " + firstName
                + lastName);
        System.out.println("Date of Service: " + date);

        System.out.println("Number of hours: " + hours);
        System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " + RATE
                * Double.parseDouble(hours));
    }

}
```

Comment: Your tips worked perfectly. Thank you providing the detailed examples. It really helped me understand it visually.

Comment: @Jessica you are welcome,  if that solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things here that make it so your code cannot correctly compile.

1. You defined hours as a `String`. This would be ok if you were only looking to display the string without manipulating it or combining it with another string. However, this line:

   ```
   System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " = RATE * hours);
   ```

   is trying to tell the compiler to multiply a type `String` with a type `double`. You cannot do this in java. Hours will have to be defined as either a `double` to match your RATE, or as a `byte`, `int`, `short`, `long` or `float`. Keep in mind that if you want partial hours (such as .5 hours) you will need to use either `double` or `float`, since these are the only two primitive data types that can be manipulated with decimals without adding a cast type.

   Alternatively, you can parse the `String` as a `double` with something that looks like `Double.parseDouble(hours)`, but this is an indirect "work-around" way of dealing with the issue, so I recommend changing the type of hours instead.
2. Whenever you declare a `final` of any data type in java, you **must** assign it a value as well. You cannot simply leave it undefined as you have in your list of variables. It should say something along the lines of

   ```
   final double RATE = 7.2;
   ```

   Because of this when you try the line:

   ```
   System.out.println("Fee before taxes: " = RATE * hours);
   ```

   the compiler calls the final which has not yet been declared, and therefor a compilation error occurs. Variables on the other hand, *can* remain uninitiated  **but they must be assigned a value that matches their data type before they are actually referenced in lines of code**. If they are not you will get a compilation error.
3. In your final print statement you have `("Fee before taxes" = RATE * hours)`.
   This is a simple syntax error. You can never have the operand `=` in a print statement. The only operand allowed (for this basic case's sake) is `+` to add more text to the string. This line should read:

   ```
   System.out.println("Fee before taxes" + (RATE * hours));
   ```

**IN SHORT** :
    Change your variable hours to type `double`, assign your `final` RATE to a   number, and change the syntax error in your final print statement. After that you should have smooth sailing.

**P.S.**
I also noticed you have two more finals called "date" and "TAX_RATE". These should be declared as well, otherwise you will come across similar errors when implementing them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you everyone for all of the clarification. Sometimes, even a good book does not explain the simple facts, but yes I definitely missed some of the obvious, like using final, and the misuse of syntax.

Comment: Practice, practice, practice and the easier it will become